# While is this function still executing after?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a simple choice game much like Rock, Paper, Scissors using Python. The problem is that after you have won, and put in the winner's name, the while loop still executes one more time. This is unacceptable! I've looked over it, and looked over it again. With my knowledge, I can't seem to work out the problem. This is a good learning moment.

Link to [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwiB337z3HPrd043bUt0ekFhZjA/edit?usp=sharing)

```
# Imports modules
import random
import math

# Welcome message
def main():

    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("// Welcome Ninja, Pirate, or Zombie //")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("\n\n")

    choose()

# Prompts user to choose class
def choose():
    choice = str(input("Make a choice! (Ninja, Pirate, or Zombie) "))

    choice = choice.lower()

    if choice == "ninja" or choice == "pirate" or choice == "zombie":
        enemy(choice)
    else:
        choose()

# Randomly selects opposing enemy
def enemy(choice):

    enemyRandom = random.randint(1,3)

    if enemyRandom == 1:
        enemy = "ninja"
    elif enemyRandom == 2:
        enemy = "pirate"
    elif enemyRandom == 3:
        enemy = "zombie"
    else:
        print("Something went wrong!")

    hit_factor(choice, enemy)

# Determines the hit factor. Certain class are weak or strong when fighting certain
# other classes
def hit_factor(choice, enemy):

    if choice == "ninja" and enemy == "ninja":
        hitFactor = 1
    elif choice == "ninja" and enemy == "pirate":
        hitFactor = 1.2
    elif choice == "ninja" and enemy == "zombie":
        hitFactor = 0.8
    elif choice == "pirate" and enemy == "ninja":
        hitFactor = 0.8
    elif choice == "pirate" and  enemy == "pirate":
        hitFactor = 1
    elif choice == "pirate" and enemy == "zombie":
        hitFactor = 1.2
    elif choice == "zombie" and enemy == "ninja":
        hitFactor = 1.2
    elif choice == "zombie" and enemy == "pirate":
        hitFactor = 0.8
    elif choice == "zombie" and enemy == "zombie":
        hitFactor = 1
    else:
        print("Something went horribly wrong.")

    enemy_hit_factor(choice, enemy, hitFactor)

# Determines the enemy's hit factor
def enemy_hit_factor(choice, enemy, hitFactor):

    if enemy == "ninja" and choice == "ninja":
        enemyHitFactor = 1
    elif enemy == "ninja" and choice == "pirate":
        enemyHitFactor = 1.2
    elif enemy == "ninja" and choice == "zombie":
        enemyHitFactor = 0.8
    elif enemy == "pirate" and choice == "ninja":
        enemyHitFactor = 0.8
    elif enemy == "pirate" and choice == "pirate":
        enemyHitFactor = 1
    elif enemy == "pirate" and choice == "zombie":
        enemyHitFactor = 1.2
    elif enemy == "zombie" and choice == "ninja":
        enemyHitFactor = 1.2
    elif enemy == "zombie" and choice == "pirate":
        enemyHitFactor = 0.8
    elif enemy == "zombie" and choice == "zombie":
        enemyHitFactor = 1
    else:
        print("Something went horribly wrong.")

    combat(choice, enemy, hitFactor, enemyHitFactor)

# Initiates combat
def combat(choice, enemy, hitFactor, enemyHitFactor):

    yourHP = 1000
    enemyHP = 1000

    print("Your HP: ", yourHP)
    print("Enemy's HP: ", enemyHP)

    over = False

    while over != True:
        isHitCalc = random.randint(1,10)
        if isHitCalc > 3:
            isHit = True
        else:
            isHit = False
            print("You missed!")

        if isHit == True:
            randomHIT = random.randint(1,100)
            randomHitDamage = math.ceil(randomHIT * hitFactor)
            enemyHP -= randomHitDamage

            if enemyHP < 0:
                enemyHP = 0

            print("You hit the enemy for ", randomHitDamage," damage.",sep='')
            print("Enemy's HP: ", enemyHP)

            if enemyHP == 0:
                file = open("wonMessage.txt", "r")
                content = file.read()
                print(content)
                over = True
                winner()

        isHitCalc2 = random.randint(1,10)
        if isHitCalc2 > 3:
            isHitMe = True
        else:
            isHitMe = False
            print("Your enemy missed!")

        if isHitMe == True:
            randomHitMe = random.randint(1,100)
            randomHitDamageMe = math.ceil(randomHitMe * enemyHitFactor)
            yourHP -= randomHitDamageMe

            if yourHP < 0:
                yourHP = 0

            print("The enemy hit you for ", randomHitDamageMe, " damage.", sep='')
            print("Your HP: ", yourHP)

            if yourHP == 0:
                file = open("lostMessage.txt", "r")
                content = file.read()
                print(content)
                over = True

# Writes winner's name to text file           
def winner():
    winner = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    infile = open("winner.txt", "w")
    infile.write("Latest winnner's name: ")
    infile.write(winner)

# Calls main
main()
```

Comment: You do lots of stuff after setting `over = True`. If you want to exit the loop immediately, use `break`.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but it can be confusing if you have both a function named `enemy` and a variable named `enemy`. I'd suggest using different names. It also makes calling that function impossible when the variable is in scope (as far as I know).

Comment: Your whole structure is a bit odd, aggregating up the variables with each function call.  It would be more traditional to `return` things at each step, e.g. make `main` look more like `user = get_user_choice(); enemy = get_enemy_choice(); user_hit_factor = hit_factor(user, enemy); enemy_hit_factor = hit_factor(enemy, user)`. This makes testing easier and reduces duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because after you call `winner()` in

```
 if enemyHP == 0:
      file = open("wonMessage.txt", "r")
      content = file.read()
      print(content)
      over = True
      winner()
```

you don't `break` out of the loop immediately.

Instead, you still proceed to process the logic below before doing the `while` loop check (`over != True`) :

```
    isHitCalc2 = random.randint(1,10)
    if isHitCalc2 > 3:
        isHitMe = True
    else:
        isHitMe = False
        print("Your enemy missed!")

    if isHitMe == True:
        randomHitMe = random.randint(1,100)
        randomHitDamageMe = math.ceil(randomHitMe * enemyHitFactor)
        yourHP -= randomHitDamageMe

        if yourHP < 0:
            yourHP = 0

        print("The enemy hit you for ", randomHitDamageMe, " damage.", sep='')
        print("Your HP: ", yourHP)

        if yourHP == 0:
            file = open("lostMessage.txt", "r")
            content = file.read()
            print(content)
            over = True
```

You can fix this specific case by adding:

```
if enemyHP == 0:
      file = open("wonMessage.txt", "r")
      content = file.read()
      print(content)
      over = True
      winner()
      break
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect. I don't believe we ever covered break in my introduction to programming class. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If it helped, feel free to mark the question as "accepted". If not, that is okay too.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function within function, once it completes the second function, it will carry on with the first:

```
>>> import time
>>> def repeat():
...     num = 0
...     while True:
...             num+=1
...             print num
...             time.sleep(1)
...             if num == 10:
...                     stop()
... 
>>> def stop():
...     print 'This program has stopped!'
...     time.sleep(1)
... 
>>> repeat()
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
This program has stopped!
11
12
13
14
15
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in repeat
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

After the `num` reaches `10`, it calls `stop()`, but once `stop()` is finished, it continues with the loop. Instead, add a `break`  or a blank `return` after calling the function:

```
>>> import time
>>> def repeat():
...     num = 0
...     while True:
...             num+=1
...             print num
...             time.sleep(1)
...             if num == 10:
...                     stop()
...                     break
... 
>>> def stop():
...     print 'This program has stopped!'
...     time.sleep(1)
... 
>>> repeat()
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
This program has stopped!
>>>
```

In your code:

```
# Imports modules
import random
import math

# Welcome message
def main():

    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("// Welcome Ninja, Pirate, or Zombie //")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("//////////////////////////////////////")
    print("\n\n")

    choose()

# Prompts user to choose class
def choose():
    choice = str(input("Make a choice! (Ninja, Pirate, or Zombie) "))

    choice = choice.lower()

    if choice == "ninja" or choice == "pirate" or choice == "zombie":
        enemy(choice)
    else:
        choose()

# Randomly selects opposing enemy
def enemy(choice):

    enemyRandom = random.randint(1,3)

    if enemyRandom == 1:
        enemy = "ninja"
    elif enemyRandom == 2:
        enemy = "pirate"
    elif enemyRandom == 3:
        enemy = "zombie"
    else:
        print("Something went wrong!")

    hit_factor(choice, enemy)

# Determines the hit factor. Certain class are weak or strong when fighting certain
# other classes
def hit_factor(choice, enemy):

    if choice == "ninja" and enemy == "ninja":
        hitFactor = 1
    elif choice == "ninja" and enemy == "pirate":
        hitFactor = 1.2
    elif choice == "ninja" and enemy == "zombie":
        hitFactor = 0.8
    elif choice == "pirate" and enemy == "ninja":
        hitFactor = 0.8
    elif choice == "pirate" and  enemy == "pirate":
        hitFactor = 1
    elif choice == "pirate" and enemy == "zombie":
        hitFactor = 1.2
    elif choice == "zombie" and enemy == "ninja":
        hitFactor = 1.2
    elif choice == "zombie" and enemy == "pirate":
        hitFactor = 0.8
    elif choice == "zombie" and enemy == "zombie":
        hitFactor = 1
    else:
        print("Something went horribly wrong.")

    enemy_hit_factor(choice, enemy, hitFactor)

# Determines the enemy's hit factor
def enemy_hit_factor(choice, enemy, hitFactor):

    if enemy == "ninja" and choice == "ninja":
        enemyHitFactor = 1
    elif enemy == "ninja" and choice == "pirate":
        enemyHitFactor = 1.2
    elif enemy == "ninja" and choice == "zombie":
        enemyHitFactor = 0.8
    elif enemy == "pirate" and choice == "ninja":
        enemyHitFactor = 0.8
    elif enemy == "pirate" and choice == "pirate":
        enemyHitFactor = 1
    elif enemy == "pirate" and choice == "zombie":
        enemyHitFactor = 1.2
    elif enemy == "zombie" and choice == "ninja":
        enemyHitFactor = 1.2
    elif enemy == "zombie" and choice == "pirate":
        enemyHitFactor = 0.8
    elif enemy == "zombie" and choice == "zombie":
        enemyHitFactor = 1
    else:
        print("Something went horribly wrong.")

    combat(choice, enemy, hitFactor, enemyHitFactor)

# Initiates combat
def combat(choice, enemy, hitFactor, enemyHitFactor):

    yourHP = 1000
    enemyHP = 1000

    print("Your HP: ", yourHP)
    print("Enemy's HP: ", enemyHP)

    over = False

    while over != True:
        isHitCalc = random.randint(1,10)
        if isHitCalc > 3:
            isHit = True
        else:
            isHit = False
            print("You missed!")

        if isHit == True:
            randomHIT = random.randint(1,100)
            randomHitDamage = math.ceil(randomHIT * hitFactor)
            enemyHP -= randomHitDamage

            if enemyHP < 0:
                enemyHP = 0

            print("You hit the enemy for ", randomHitDamage," damage.",sep='')
            print("Enemy's HP: ", enemyHP)

            if enemyHP == 0:
                file = open("wonMessage.txt", "r")
                content = file.read()
                print(content)
                over = True
                winner()
                return

        isHitCalc2 = random.randint(1,10)
        if isHitCalc2 > 3:
            isHitMe = True
        else:
            isHitMe = False
            print("Your enemy missed!")

        if isHitMe == True:
            randomHitMe = random.randint(1,100)
            randomHitDamageMe = math.ceil(randomHitMe * enemyHitFactor)
            yourHP -= randomHitDamageMe

            if yourHP < 0:
                yourHP = 0

            print("The enemy hit you for ", randomHitDamageMe, " damage.", sep='')
            print("Your HP: ", yourHP)

            if yourHP == 0:
                file = open("lostMessage.txt", "r")
                content = file.read()
                print(content)
                over = True

# Writes winner's name to text file           
def winner():
    winner = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    infile = open("winner.txt", "w")
    infile.write("Latest winnner's name: ")
    infile.write(winner)

# Calls main
main()
```

This basically adds a `return` after the `winner()` in this code:

```
if enemyHP == 0:
    file = open("wonMessage.txt", "r")
    content = file.read()
    print(content)
    over = True
    winner()
    return
```